# insert phpmysql form without refreshing the page

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, webforms

I am new to programming so please kindly help me with my script,

```
        <?php
if(isset($_FILES['files'])){
    $errors= array();
    foreach($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'] as $key => $tmp_name ){
        $file_name = $key.$_FILES['files']['name'][$key];
        $file_size =$_FILES['files']['size'][$key];
        $file_tmp =$_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$key];
        $file_type=$_FILES['files']['type'][$key];  
        if($file_size > 2097152){
            $errors[]='File size must be less than 2 MB';
        }       
        $query="INSERT into upload_data (`USER_ID`,`FILE_NAME`,`FILE_SIZE`,`FILE_TYPE`) VALUES('$user_id','$file_name','$file_size','$file_type'); ";
        $desired_dir="user_data";
        if(empty($errors)==true){
            if(is_dir($desired_dir)==false){
                mkdir("$desired_dir", 0700);        // Create directory if it does not exist
            }
            if(is_dir("$desired_dir/".$file_name)==false){
                move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"$desired_dir/".$file_name);
            }else{                                  // rename the file if another one exist
                $new_dir="$desired_dir/".$file_name.time();
                 rename($file_tmp,$new_dir) ;               
            }
         mysql_query($query);           
        }else{
                print_r($errors);
        }
    }
    if(empty($error)){
        echo "Success";
    }
}
?>


<form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="files[]" multiple/>
    <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

i am using this script, it uploads the image but it does not insert values into the database and also i don't want my page to refresh, so please help me with the code

Answer (score 0):

Generally it might be better to use a third party script like Uploadify like this; http://www.uploadify.com/

This will allow you to do as you need, even with the same back end script.

It also has a progress bar.